# Android ActionBar NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to enable the Android ActionBar, however it doesn't work for me.

Here is my **MainActivity**:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.show();
        //more code............
```

and here is the logcat:

```
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.salebook/com.example.salebook.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at com.example.salebook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:130)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-04 16:31:09.423: E/AndroidRuntime(1441):     ... 11 more
```

Where line 130 is `anctionBar.show()` and I have in **res/menu/menu.xml**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/itemid_0"
        android:title="Action Item 0"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item android:id="@+id/itemid_1"
        android:title="Action Item 1"
        android:orderInCategory="0" />
    <item android:id="@+id/itemid_2"
        android:title="Action Item 2"
        android:orderInCategory="0" />
    <item android:id="@+id/itemid_3"
        android:title="Action Item 3"
        android:orderInCategory="0" />
</menu>
```

I didn't find the problem. Hope someone help me.

Thanks.

Also,in the appThem style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
```

Comment: What is line number 130 in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: @Pragnani `actionBar.show()`

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379916/adding-an-action-bar-to-theme-black-notitlebar-android

Comment: i debugged it right now, and i see the actionBar is null... i looked at this post and it didnt help me

Comment: i also added this line,as was wrote in the link:     getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
however its the same error..

Comment: @AdirRahamim check my answer and you should remove this this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: apparently you don't have an action_bar

Comment: @AdirRahamim Have you tried what I have suggested..?

Comment: @ Pragnani, i tried what you suggested, however its the same problem (NullpointerException)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You Actionbar returns null because you don't have actionbar but you are requesting using getActionbar()

Make sure that you've window feature to show your actionbar, That is required for the actionbar to show. Check the below links for more details.
...check this question [getActionBar returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031180/getactionbar-returns-null) And also check this link for the more information on your problem http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html

Answer (score 6):

You Remove

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

in "application" from AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually see an actionbar if you remove the line `actionBar.show()`?
If not, it could be related to your theme, e.g. `Theme.Light.NoActionBar`.

Comment: still the same NullPointerException Although that i removed this line

Comment: Do you have a custom theme for your app/activity?

Comment: in the manifest.xml, i have this line: android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: And what is declared in the `AppTheme` style?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>,   i added it also to the main thread

Answer (score 0):

go to the AndroidManifest.xml and replace

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

by

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```